# apache2 service Failed on restart - Failed to start apache2.service: Unit not found

Tags: php, apache, server

when I try to restart the apache server I got following response.

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start apache2.service
>
> Failed to start apache2.service: Unit not found.

Comment: Isn't it httpd.service? `systemctl restart httpd`

Comment: USER apache
HOME /usr/share/httpd
this is php information ther server is apache. @Daan

Comment: Yes apache is the user but the process is httpd. Try `systemctl restart httpd` or `apachectl restart`

Comment: sudo systemctl restart httpd is worked thank you @Daan

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using different service of apache.

run this if you are using the same service.

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

or

```
apachectl restart
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using latest Linux try following
 -  Check your service name using following command

```
 # systemctl list-units --type service
```

Above command will list all the services, find the right service name you want to restart 
 - use following to restart or reload service
e.g I use my restart service httpd24-httpd.service

```
# systemctl restart httpd24-httpd.service
or # systemctl reload httpd24-httpd.service
```